# Dynamically referencing a String in Strings.xml in Android

Tags: android

Say I have the following my strings.xml file:

```
<string name="string0">Lorem</string>
<string name="string1">ipsum</string>
<string name="string2">dolor</string>
```

In my activity an ID is set based on the clicking of a button.  If the top button is clicked the id is 0, middle is 1 and bottom button is 2.

What would the syntax look like for referencing one of the three strings?

I know R.string.string0 works but I want to do something equivalent to:

```
R.string["string"+currentID]
```

where I derive the string to use based on the ID.

Just not sure what the syntax would look like in Java/Android.

Thanks in advance,
Tony

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you not just use a string array in your resources instead of separate string entries?

Comment: Thank you so much.  Yes, I can do this, just didn't think of it.

Answer (score 1):

That's a bad approach. It's slow. It'd be better to have an internal integer array with all the R.string IDs.

If you really insist on using a string-based approach, use `Resources.getIdentifier()`.

Comment: Thank you.  I would mark this as the anser but Kurru answered first.

Comment: Uh, not really. You see that mine came 3 minutes earlier (look at the "answered n mins ago").

Comment: Why would you use a interger array? Would a string array not be better?

Comment: @Kurru: Why load all the strings into memory? That's wasteful. Integers are much more compact, and you don't have to reload the strings if the user decides to change the language. Of course, if it's only a handful of strings, and if you use them A LOT, then it's faster to cache them into a string array.

Comment: If they're hand typed into the program I doubt theres any significant waste.